# Cannot reference dynamically referenced controls

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, reference

I am using the instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459230/dynamic-variable-name-use-in-c-sharp-for-winforms) to access a few `textboxes` that are already in my `Winform`. For some reason I get the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I am quite sure that the code is correct but as soon as I try to access any `property` of the control I get that error. My code is below - can anybody spot what I am doing wrong?

```
TextBox textbox = this.Controls["txtLiveBlock" + ((i + 1) * (j + 1)).ToString()] as TextBox;
textbox.Text = "TESTING";
```

Note that my `Textbox` is called "txtLiveBlock1" and i = 0, j = 0. I have even tried sending the section `txtLiveBlock" + ((i + 1) * (j + 1)` to a `MessageBox` and I get "txtLiveBlock1" back.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the control is actually a textbox? I would imagine the indexer will throw an exception if no control with the given name was found, so it's most likely the cast is failing. I would cast to a `TextBox` directly instead of using `as` to see which it is.

Comment: I added the control through the GUI toolbox. I'm quite sure it is a `TextBox`.

Comment: In which thread is your code running? Could it be some background thread?

Comment: Make sure the TextBox isn't inside another container control, like a panel or a group box.

Comment: Aaah...I think that may be the issue. It is inside a `tabControl`. I am experimenting now...

Comment: Then change `this` to the container control, and if it's a tab control, you have to have the right TabPage control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the control is inside another container control, like a panel or a TabPage, you would have to reference that container control:

```
TextBox textbox = tabPage1.Controls["txtLiveBlock" + ((i + 1) * (j + 1)).ToString()] as TextBox;
textbox.Text = "TESTING";
```

Answer (score 1):

Break it down:

```
string name = "txtLiveBlock" + ((i + 1) * (j + 1)).ToString();
Control ctrl = this.Controls[name]; // returns null if the control is not found
TextBox textbox = ctrl as TextBox;  // returns null if ctrl is not a TextBox
textbox.Text = "TESTING";   // if textbox is null, throws NullReferenceException
```

Step through this code: where does it break?

You are getting a `NullReferenceException` on the last line, which means that `textbox` is ending up as null. This could happen in a couple of ways:

`this.Controls[name]` returns null if the control is not in the list of controls on the form. Note that controls inside of other controls are not in this list - e.g. controls in a panel are in that panel's `Controls` list, not the form's.

`ctrl as TextBox` returns null if the `ctrl` is not actually a TextBox.

If you step through the code and mouse-over the variables as you go, you should be able to see what is happening.

Comment: OK- so `textbox` is null? check whether `ctrl` is also null. If not, check the type of `ctrl` - it's not a TextBox.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I'm something of a beginner.

Comment: I added a picture in the question. Doesn't this mean it is a `TextBox`?

Comment: Looks like it *is* a TextBox from your picture. If you mouse over the variable while stepping through the code, you should be able to see its properties, or "null" if it's null.

Comment: it is indeed null.... sorry to sound like such an idiot, but what does that mean?

Comment: @LarsTech just mentioned that it may be screwed if it is inside a container. It is actually inside a `tabControl`. I am trying to experiment with this now...

Comment: `this.Control` returns null if there's no control by that name. Does the textbox exist on the same form as the button that this code lives in? When debugging, you can also mouse over `this.Controls` and take a look inside to see what's in there.

Comment: Ah - yes, if it's in a container, you need to refer to `thatContainer.Controls` instead.

Comment: Great! I updated my answer to cover the material in the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling this code?  If it's in the constructor before `InitializeComponent()` gets called, then the Controls collection is empty at this point (although if it's empty, I would expect a KeyNotFoundException instead of returning a null value, but I'm not in a position to test it right now).

Comment: It gets triggered by a button after all these controls are created.