# Include "for" loop in button name

Tags: c#, button, for-loop

How can I include the "for" loop in the name of the button?

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            button[i].Text = "0";
        }
```

Is there any way to make this work?
Thank you!

Comment: What's the result that you want to achieve? A button with a label that reads `0000000000`?

Comment: Just to add the same text for 10 buttons efficiently.

Comment: ... and of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055648/converting-string-to-a-control-name-in-c-sharp) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248989/how-to-concat-variable-integer-in-control-name-in-vb-net) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459230/dynamic-variable-name-use-in-c-sharp-for-winforms) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578957/equivalent-to-refer-to-control-by-variable-name) ...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can access a button with it's name like this:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        string buttonName = "button" + i;
        this.Controls[buttonName].Text = "0";
    }
```

Comment: I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the second line of code.

Comment: @user2992015: On `{`?

Comment: on "this.Controls[buttonName].Text = "0";"

Comment: Check your button names and change buttonName's value. What is your button names ? If your button names like "button1","button2" .. this code should work..you are getting that error because your button names are different

Comment: My buttons names are "button1" to "button10".

Comment: Where is your buttons, inside of your Form or Panel ??

Comment: Button are inside my form. I tried to write this code: "this.Controls[button1].Text = "0";" and got "Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments"

Answer (score 1):

Initialize an array of `Button`:

```
Button btnsarr = new Button[ DefineTheSize ]();
```

and add all `buttons` in it:

```
btnarr[0] = button1;
btnarr[1] = button2;
btnarr[2] = button3;
// and so on
```

now you can use this array in the you want.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= btnarr.Length; i++)
{
    btnsarr[i].Text = "0";
}
```

Comment: You are adding same button multiple times in an array.

Comment: @RohitVats That was just a sample. Anyway ! I've corrected it.

Comment: Moreover, i think there is no need of creating an array at all. Buttons can be accessed from `Controls collection` like [Selman22](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20773234/632337) mentioned in his answer already.

Comment: @RohitVats: Unless there are *only* those buttons around, the complete collection of contorls would have to be filtered, which is not a clean solution compared to an array that contains exactly the buttons that should be processed.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Sorry mate didn't get you. All collection will be filtered. What?

Comment: @RohitVats: If you put the buttons that should be included in the loop into an array once upon initialization, you can simply loop over the array. If you loop directly over the controls collection, you will have to spend some additional effort on checking which controls you actually want every time you loop over the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is:

```
foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray())
     button.Text = "0";
```

Comment: This will break as soon as there is any button on the form that is not supposed to be subject to the text assignment.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper I dont think so there is any such button which not support text assignment

Comment: The OP doesn't state whether or not there is any such button. Even if there isn't any right now, I'd be careful about calling something that breaks on the first tiny change to the surrounding UI as the "best way".

Comment: @O. R. Magger So how should I check this?  C# provide to check so?

Comment: Instead of using `this.Controls`, you can add the buttons you want to treat with the loop into a list or an array, as shown in [Shaharyar's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1910920/shaharyar) answer, and then iterate over that.